# What happens when bowler deliberately delays while bowling?

Tags: rules, cricket

I searched for Law to deal with the situation where the bowler deliberately pauses or delays while bowling but found nothing. Is there a law that I did not found, if there isn't then what does umpire do in this situation?

I am asking for situation when bowler may use this tactic to distract the batsman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be covered by [Law 42.9 (Fair and unfair play, Time wasting by the fielding side)](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-42-fair-and-unfair-play/):

> If either umpire considers that the progress of an over is unnecessarily slow, or time is being wasted in any other way by the captain of the fielding side or by any other fielder, at the first instance the umpire concerned shall [ ... ] warn the captain of the fielding side, indicating that this is a first and final warning.
>
> [ ... ]
>
> If either umpire considers that there is any further waste of time in that innings by any fielder, he shall [ ... ] direct the captain of the fielding side to suspend the bowler forthwith. The bowler thus suspended shall not be allowed to bowl again in that innings.

The incident would also be reported to the Governing Body responsible for the match.

Comment: So it may be called as dead ball in bowler parts.

Comment: Yes, one of the bits I've skipped there is "if the ball is in play, call and signal Dead ball."